# Как обратиться к элементу объекта в nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

После запроса к базе я получаю объект [ RowDataPacket { id: 1, login: 'Uri', password: '9696GORYACHEV' } ]
как вывести просто id?
Пробовал i[id]/i['id'] - не выводит
Пробую

```
for(var kay in i) {
        var w = i[kay];
        response.send(w);
    }
```

Выводит полностью весь объект

Comment: `i[0].id` .......

Comment: express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead index.js:29:14
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 1

Comment: А вы документацию пробовали читать?

Comment: да, а в чем проблема? Он не может выводить первый элемент?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Строго говоря, в документации express'а этот момент как раз опущен, там сказано просто: `The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array.` А вот про то, что если параметр - это `Number`, то вызывается `sendStatus` c этим параметром, нужно догадываться. :)

Comment: @narem у вас `id` - это число, а `response.send()` в этом случае ведет себя неочевидным образом. Приведите к строке, хотя бы так: `var w = i[kay] + '';`